# Find the history of all commands entered in a specific location in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, history, bash-history

Is there a way that I could find history of all commands (or 100 most recent commands) that were entered in a specific directory?

For example, imagine I am in `mona@goku:~/research/code/phosa/external/frankmocap$`

is there a way for me to figure history of all commands I have entered when I was located in this directory in Terminal?

Comment: Have you added any features to your bash history?  eg. I have mine record date & time for each command... If you record all commands (I don't), then you could always list commands after the `cd` into the required directory until you exit, but extracts won't know if you closed/re-opened a new session (date & time may help with this, or whatever other clues you added to your history you haven't told us about).

Comment: you are looking for auditd

Comment: In addition to auditd, [how to use auditd to record all user command history](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-audit/2013-October/msg00020.html) has 2 more suggestions: "Old Shell Game" and snoopy. There's also [bash_franzi](https://gitlab.com/bitinerant/bash_franzi) (full disclosure - I was involved in this last one).